# Javascript string/variable concatenation without space

Tags: php, javascript

while using a ajax script, I made the php part echo a value then in the jQuery part I alert it.

So we have something like this:

```
<?php echo "1"; ?>

//Javascript
alert("the value is"+phpvalue);
```

The alert shows up like "the value is 1". Now my question is how do I remove the space between the "the value is" and +phpvalue? So it show up like "the value is1". I tried trim() on the php part but it doesn't change anything.

Apreciate any help and sorry if it is a noob question =/

Comment: You didn't show us how `phpvalue` is being set (just that it's coming from an AJAX request). Do you have any spaces before your opening `<?php` tag?

Comment: your current code should alert `the value is1`

Comment: `trim` should remove whitespace if it exists

Comment: @Colin, you were right. Didn't know that I should'nt have any spaces before the php tag. Sorry for the noob question =/

Comment: add a <?php session_start() ?> before that's were the space came from.

Comment: @user2084627 This question is too localized. Please close/delete the question if you have solved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In http response can be some other caracters than what you print. For example, if there is spaces before php tag .. BOM character in the begining of the php file... so if you trim just the variable, that does not detemrimate, that you get purely the variable on client side without junk characters.

So you should use trim on client side in javascript:
For example jQuery trim (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/)

```
   alert("the value is"+$.trim(phpvalue));
```

Or use nativ js trim function from phpjsorg (http://phpjs.org/functions/trim/):

```
   alert("the value is"+trim(phpvalue));
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you want but here are two situations

```
If you just are dealing with excess whitespace on the beginning or end of the string you can use trim(), ltrim() orrtrim() to remove that.

If you are dealing with extra spaces within a string consider a preg_replace of multiple whitespaces " "* with a single whitespace " "

$foo = preg_replace( '/\s+/', ' ', $foo );
```